# How to read MS Teams version

Tags: c#, version, microsoft-teams

How to read MS Teams full version with major and minor version details in a C# code? I hope this statement is self explanatory. Let me know if this does not explain the question clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Teams.exe is in the Microsoft\Teams\Current folder in local application data.

You need to get the product version of the VersionInfo, so this should do the trick:

```cs
var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo($@"{appData}\Microsoft\Teams\current\teams.exe");
var version = myFileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
```